# Assign value to new column based on values in 2 other columns

Tags: r

Here is an example code:

```
Group <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B","B", "B")
Actor <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 2, 6, 4, 3)
df <- data.frame(Group,Actor)
df
```

Now, what I want to do is to create three new columns (Sex, Status, SexStat) based on the data in the Group and Actor columns.
For example, if Group = A and Actor = 1, then Sex = M, Status = Dom, and SexStat = DomM. If Group = A and Actor = 3, then Sex = F, Status = Med, and SexStat = MedF (and so on).

The numbers do not always align with the same rank/sexes in every group, and with 5500 lines of data, I would love it if there was a way to not do this manually! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create conditions for *Sex* and *Status* and then paste them to create *SexStat*

```
library(dplyr)

Group <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B","B", "B")
Actor <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 2, 6, 4, 3)
df <- data.frame(Group,Actor)
df

df %>% 
  mutate(
    Sex = case_when(
      Group == "A" & Actor == 1 ~ "M",
      Group == "A" & Actor == 3 ~ "F",
      TRUE ~ ""
    ),
    Status = case_when(
      Group == "A" & Actor == 1 ~ "Dom",
      Group == "A" & Actor == 3 ~ "Med",
      TRUE ~ ""
    ),
    SexStat = paste0(Status,Sex)
  )

   Group Actor Sex Status SexStat
1      A     1   M    Dom    DomM
2      A     3   F    Med    MedF
3      A     6                   
4      A     4                   
5      A     1   M    Dom    DomM
6      B     2                   
7      B     2                   
8      B     6                   
9      B     4                   
10     B     3
```

Answer (score 2):

We may do this with a key/value dataset by joining

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
keydat <- tibble(Group = "A", Actor = c(1, 3), Sex = c("M", "F"), Status = c("Dom", "Med"))
df %>% 
    left_join(keydat) %>%
    mutate(across(c(Sex, Status), replace_na, ""), 
         SexStat = str_c(Status, Sex))
```

-output

```
Group Actor Sex Status SexStat
1      A     1   M    Dom    DomM
2      A     3   F    Med    MedF
3      A     6                   
4      A     4                   
5      A     1   M    Dom    DomM
6      B     2                   
7      B     2                   
8      B     6                   
9      B     4                   
10     B     3
```